# I changed the rest pose, and now I can’t x flip poses

Tags: animation, rigging

So I made the mistake of setting a new rest pose so my characters hands weren't mirroring each other, and now I can paste the pose mirrored on the x axis. All the solutions I could find said just start the rig over, but I have spent like over twenty ours on this thing and I refuse to do it again, especially with the weight paint. So does any one have a solution to make it so I can x-flip poses?

Comment: You could just load an autosave

Comment: Non of the auto saves available were taken before I changed the rest pose, so no go.